# Binary Search Trees - all traversal methods work wrong

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I'm working on binary search trees right now, but I have some problems with traversal methods. It doesn't print correct data. It even looks like I'm losing it from memory. Everything works fine until adding fourth element. Can you have a look here?

Header file:

```
    #ifndef TREENODE_H
    #define TREENODE_H
    #include<cstdlib>
    #include<iostream>

    template <class T>
    class Bintree
    {
        struct Node
        {
            T val;
            Node *left;
            Node *right;
        };
        public:
        Bintree();
        Bintree(const Bintree&);
        ~Bintree();
        Node* root;
        void preorder(Node*);
        void inorder(Node*);
        void postorder(Node*);
        Node* minimum(Node*);
        Node* findelement(Node*);
        Node* maximum(Node*);
        void add(T);
        void del(T);
        void delnode(Node*);
    };

    #endif
```

treenode.cpp file

```
#include "treenode.h"

template<class T>
Bintree<T>::Bintree()
{
    root = nullptr;
}

template<class T>
Bintree<T>::Bintree(const Bintree<T>& source)
{
    root = copy(source.root, NULL);
}

template<class T>
Bintree<T>::~Bintree()
{
    delete root;
}

template<class T>
void Bintree<T>::preorder(Node* root)
{
    if(root==nullptr) return;
    std::cout<<root->val<<"\t";
    preorder(root->left);
    preorder(root->right);
}

template<class T>
void Bintree<T>::inorder(Node* root)
{
    if(root==nullptr) return;
    inorder(root->left);
    std::cout<<root->val<<"\t";
    inorder(root->right);
}

template<class T>
void Bintree<T>::postorder(Node* root)
{
    if(root==nullptr) return;
    postorder(root->left);
    postorder(root->right);
    std::cout<<root->val<<"\t";
}

template<class T>
typename Bintree<T>::Node* Bintree<T>::minimum(Node* root)
{
    if(!root->left) return root;
    else
    {
        while(root->left!=nullptr)
            root = root->left;
        return root;
    }
}

    template<class T>
    typename Bintree<T>::Node* Bintree<T>::maximum(Node* root)
    {
        if(!root->right) return root;
        else
        {
            while(root->right!=nullptr)
                root = root->right;
            return root;
        }
    }

    template<class T>
    void Bintree<T>::add(T x)
    {
        Node *p = new Node;
        p->left = nullptr;
        p->right = nullptr;
        p->val = x;
        if(root == nullptr)
            root = p;
        else
        {
            for(;;)
            {
                if(x<root->val)
                {
                    if(!root->left)
                    {
                        root->left = p;
                        break;
                    }
                    else root = root->left;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(!root->right)
                    {
                        root->right = p;
                        break;
                    }
                    else root = root->right;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

main.cpp file

```
#include "treenode.cpp" // When I write treenode.h it gives me
//an error like `Undefined reference to...` member functions. Why?

int main()
{
    try
    {
        Bintree<char> BST;
        BST.add('a');
        BST.add('c');
        BST.add('x');
        BST.add('y');
        std::cout<<"min: "<<BST.minimum(BST.root)->val;
        std::cout<<"max: "<<BST.maximum(BST.root)->val<<"\n";
        BST.preorder(BST.root);
    }
    catch (std::exception const &e)
    {
        std::cerr<<"Exception caught: "<<e.what()<<'\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Thanks, didn't even notice my debugger haven't pointed so many options out. I'll check this out

Comment: You should never #include a cpp file.  Since your treenode.cpp contains only template class function definitions, I would rename the file treenode.hpp or treenode.tpp, then include it at the end of treenode.h.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your traversals as such.

Your `add` function always modifies the root.
It should only do that when inserting into an empty tree.

Use a local variable for traversal:

```
template<class T>
void Bintree<T>::add(T x)
{
    Node *p = new Node;
    p->left = nullptr;
    p->right = nullptr;
    p->val = x;
    if(root == nullptr)
        root = p;
    else
    {
        Node* current = root;
        for(;;)
        {
            if(x<current->val)
            {
                if(!current->left)
                {
                    current->left = p;
                    break;
                }
                else current = current->left;
            }
            else
            {
                if(!current->right)
                {
                    current->right = p;
                    break;
                }
                else current = current->right;
            }
        }
    }
}
```